# Payment method not showing

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, graphql

I have integrated "klarna payments" in magento 2.4.3 EE

When i use `graphQL` mutation on cart id, i can see `klarna payment method` in `available_payment_methods` but when i call the endpoint for the same in `POSTMAN`
i do not see that `klarna payment method` in response.

**Any thoughts what can be the issue ?**

Comment: Any thoughts what can be the issue with it?

Comment: Any thoughts what can be the issue with it

Comment: try this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/altair-graphql-client/flnheeellpciglgpaodhkhmapeljopja?hl=en